# How to reshape boolean columns from wide to long table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a wide dataframe, with several columns of that describe the type of each row using booleans.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'e'],
                   'Type One': [True, False, False, False], 
                   'Type Two': [False, True, True, True]})
```

which looks like:

```
   ID Name  Type One  Type Two
0   0    x      True     False
1   1    y     False      True
2   2    z     False      True
3   3    e     False      True
```

I would prefer that this dataframe be in a long format, such that each row is matched to a Type:

```
   ID Name  Type  
0   0    x     Type One
1   1    y     Type Two
2   2    z     Type Two
3   3    e     Type Two
```

Note: I believe that all ID's have only 1 type, (so where Type One is True, Type N must be False).

Comment: `df['Type'] = df.filter(like='Type').idxmax(1)`

Comment: @ALollz Damn that's a lot more simpler than mine...

Comment: @ALollz the original post's column names were chosen for simplicity's sake... so I supposed you'd have to list each column name and pass those as an argument to filter()?

Comment: @Eli then in that case just pass a list to select columns by labels instead of using filter: `df[['Type One', 'Type Two']].idxmax(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `dot`:

```
s = df[['Type One', 'Type Two']]
s.dot(s.columns)
```

Output:

```
0    Type One
1    Type Two
2    Type Two
3    Type Two
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that this is essentially dot product. If my original assumption (`all ID's have only 1 type, (so where Type One is True, Type N must be False)`) isn't true, will there be any way of knowing? Will this dot() still work?

Comment: `s.sum(axis=1).eq(1).all()` would check that condition for you. Dot still works, but it would return concatenation of all positive column names in that row.

Answer (score -1):

```
df['Type'] = None
df.loc[df['Type One'], 'Type'] = 'Type One'
df.loc[df['Type Two'], 'Type'] = 'Type Two'
df.drop(columns=['Type One', 'Type Two'], inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   ID Name      Type
0   0    x  Type One
1   1    y  Type Two
2   2    z  Type Two
3   3    e  Type Two
```